Merge multiple datasets in Power Query
I have two datasets with same structure, something like



Column A
Column B
Column DS1
Column C
Column D




Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell DS1a
Cell 4
Cell 5


Cell 6
Cell 7
Cell DS1b
Cell 9
Cell 10



and



Column A
Column B
Column DS2
Column C
Column D




Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell DS2a
Cell 4
Cell 5


Cell 11
Cell 12
Cell DS2b
Cell 13
Cell 14



I have merged them (Full Outer) and I have got
| Column A | Column B | Column DS1 | Column C | Column D | DS2.Column A | DS2.Column B | DS2.Column DS2 | DS2.Column C | DS2.Column D |

but I wish to end up with a table that looks like this



Column A
Column B
Column DS1
Column DS2
Column C
Column D




Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell DS1a
Cell DS2a
Cell 4
Cell 5


Cell 6
Cell 7
Cell DS1b
null
Cell 9
Cell 10


Cell 11
Cell 12
null
Cell DS2b
Cell 13
Cell 14



How can I achieve that?

I'm not sure how realistic your example is, but using the data you have posted,

after you perform the Merge,
instead of expanding the merged table,
you need to replace the null values in the original table with the matching values from the merged table
and then add the Column DS2 to the final table.
Then you have to re-arrange the column order and sort the table appropriately.

This code works with your posted data to do that:Read the code comments and explore the Applied Steps to better understand the algorithm
let

//Read in the tables
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    colNames1 = Table.ColumnNames(Source1),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,List.Transform(colNames1, each {_, type text})),

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    colNames2 = Table.ColumnNames(Source2),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,List.Transform(colNames2, each {_, type text})),

//We will do the join using the column names that are common to both tables
    commonColNames=List.Intersect({colNames1,colNames2}),

    Join = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type1",commonColNames,#"Changed Type2",commonColNames,"Joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),

//Replace the unmatched (nulls) in the left table with the values from the right table
    #"Replace Nulls" = Table.TransformRows(Join, (r)=>
        Record.TransformFields(r, List.Transform(commonColNames, (cn)=>{cn, each if _ =null 
            then Table.Column(r[Joined], cn){0} else _}))),

//Add Column DS2 to the records
    #"Add DS2" = List.Accumulate(
        #"Replace Nulls",
        {},
        (s,c)=> s & {Record.AddField(c,"Column DS2", Table.Column(c[Joined],"Column DS2"){0})}),

//Convert the list of records to a table and expand it
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Add DS2", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),    
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", List.Distinct(List.Combine({colNames1,colNames2}))),

//Set the desired column order
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Column1",{"Column A", "Column B", "Column DS1", "Column DS2", "Column C", "Column D"}),

//Add a column to sort on and then do the sort
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "SortOn", each Number.From(Text.Split([Column A]," "){1}), type number),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Custom",{{"SortOn", Order.Ascending}}),

//Remove the column we used for sorting
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"SortOn"}),

//Set the data types for the columns
    #"Type Columns" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns"), each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Type Columns"

Table1

Table2

Merged Tables


Thank you for your suggestion but I figured that out ... since these datasets where a subset of a bigger dataset (let's call it MainDS), extracted via some conditions, I added an index column in the MainDS that was carried over in the other resulting datasets. Then I appended all datasets extracted from the MainDS, removed the duplicates from the index column and merged (Inner Join) the MainDS to the datasets appended pointing at the index column to obtain the desired output.
